# Using || to define default variable to variable

Tags: go

How is the equivalent of `var name = value || value2;` in Go? I'm trying to:

```
src := c.Name || path.Base(c.Src)
```

But this is not valid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One way to go about it (pun intended)

```
src := c.Name
if src == "" {
    src = path.Base(c.Src)
}
```

or if you like `else`s

```
var src string
if c.Name != "" {
    src = c.Name
else {
    src = path.Base(c.Src)
}
```